# How do I make my "Main" function execute in the correct order?

Tags: c, function

I'm trying to do a conditional and if-else loop
on this problem however, my main function isn't executing the steps in the order I had intended.

```
#include<stdio.h>
    void draft(int, char);
    void main()
    {
        int age = 0;
        char sex;
        printf("How old are you?");
        scanf_s("%d", &age);
        printf("Please enter your sex.(M or F)");
        scanf_s("%c", &sex);
        draft(age,sex);
        system("pause");
        return;
    }
    void draft(int age,char sex)
    {
        if (age>= 21 && sex=="M")
        {
            printf("Congratulations son, You will be going off to Syria to fight for your country.\n");
        }
        else if (age >= 18 && sex == "M")
        {
            printf("Congratulations son, You will be going off to Vietnam to fight for your country.\n");
        }
        else if (age < 18 && sex == "M")
        {
            printf("Sorry Son you're still too young.\n");
        }
        else if (age >= 21 && sex == "F")
        {
            printf("Sorry,miss, only men can serve.\n");
        }
        else if (age >= 18 && sex == "F")
        {
            printf("Sorry,little lady, only men can serve.\n");
        }
        else if (age < 18 && sex == "F")
        {
            printf("Sorry,little girl, only men can serve.\n");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Please enter age and sex.");
        }
        return;
    }
```

The user is prompted for his age but after that is entered it will go directly to the last ELSE statement of the "draft" function without giving the user the opportunity to enter the sex.

Comment: I don't see how that could happen based on the code here.  Step through line by line in a debugger.

Comment: @EricJ.: I guess you didn't see `scanf_s("%c", &sex);`?

Comment: What happens if you just use `scanf`?

Comment: @EOF: The OP claims that after `scanf_s("%d", &age);` the program jumps to the else branch of an as-yet-uncalled function.  Do you mean just that the printf expected and the printf in the else branch are similar?

Comment: @EricJ.: After you input a number for `scanf_s("%d", &age);`, what usually remains in the input buffer, and can match `%c` in the next `scanf_s()`?

Comment: Also, integers and characters are unlikely to ever compare equal to string literals.

Comment: @EOF my understanding is that this part assigns a character to the "sex" variable which is then used in the second argument of the DRAFT function .

Comment: @JustoMontoya: Sure it does. The question is *which character* it assigns. Hint: Try comparing the the character you get with `'\n'`...

Comment: Now I recall why I stopped programming in C more than a decade ago.

Comment: @EricJ.: Because some people write bad code?

Comment: correction, after the user inputs the age, the printf-statement on line 9 is also evaluated but then the it goes directly to the last ELSE part of the DRAFT function without giving the opportunity to input the sex.

Comment: @EOF: Because it is very easy to write bad code in C, compared to e.g. Java or C#.

Comment: You should change the strings like "M" to characters like 'M' so that characters are compared.

Comment: The function is called `main`, not `Main` (C is case-sensitive). And `void main()` should be `int main(void)`.

Comment: @EOF I see what you mean by the '\n' character now. Thank you. I changed the order of the scanf- to make the sex one go first. In placing the age scanf first the \n character is assigned to the sex variable. thanks again.

Comment: @JustoMontoya: You know, you *could* also change the second `scanf_s()` to `scanf_s(" %c", &sex);` and keep the order the same.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are using scanf to parse input from stdin. However this just treats it as a stream. Your program actually works if you enter something like `32F` at the first input.

[Edit for clarity: You program is not actually jumping oddly, what is happening is that the second scanf returns immediately with data from stdin which wasn't read with the first one. In this case it is the return character from when user pressed enter key. So it returns immediately with a value that is not your 'M' or 'F', hence it runs the final else. There is no "out of order" happening]

Note: There is a second problem in your `draft()` function. You use `"M"` and `"F"` which are strings (character arrays), whereas you actually need to use `'M'` and `'F'` which are single characters.

What you are wanting is to read a single line and parse it at a time. So I suggest the following change. I have replaced the `scanfs` with a `fgets` which will read a single line. Then use `sscanf` to parse that line.

```
#include<stdio.h>

void draft(int, char);
int main()
{
    int age = 0;
    char sex;
    char line[100] = {0};

    printf("How old are you?");
    fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin);
    sscanf(line, "%d", &age);
    printf("Please enter your sex.(M or F)");
    fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin);
    sscanf(line, "%c", &sex);
    draft(age,sex);

    return 0;
}
void draft(int age,char sex)
{
    if (age>= 21 && sex=='M')
    {
        printf("Congratulations son, You will be going off to Syria to fight for your country.\n");
    }
    else if (age >= 18 && sex == 'M')
    {
        printf("Congratulations son, You will be going off to Vietnam to fight for your country.\n");
    }
    else if (age < 18 && sex == 'M')
    {
        printf("Sorry Son you're still too young.\n");
    }
    else if (age >= 21 && sex == 'F')
    {
        printf("Sorry,miss, only men can serve.\n");
    }
    else if (age >= 18 && sex == 'F')
    {
        printf("Sorry,little lady, only men can serve.\n");
    }
    else if (age < 18 && sex == 'F')
    {
        printf("Sorry,little girl, only men can serve.\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Please enter age and sex.");
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: No. Don't even start with `gets()`. It's deprecated for good reasons. Also, if you got `draft()` working, you should probably post the necessary changes for that too.

Comment: @EOF: `gets` isn't merely deprecated; as of the 2011 ISO C standard it's been completely removed from the language. And I agree: don't even suggest using `gets`.

Comment: I've edited it to use `fgets`. I was just using `gets` as the simplest thing to get it to work.

Comment: @waterjuice: The only question is: *does* it actually work with just the edits you have posted?

Comment: I've edited your answer to remove any reference to `gets()`; there's no point in mentioning it.

Comment: Yes, I compiled and ran the program (in OSX)

Comment: @waterjuice: Really? You didn't need to edit anything in `draft()`? Are you absolutely sure?

Comment: Oh right I did need to make a change, I did that right at the start and forgot. The `"M"` and `"F"` need to be changed to `'M'` and `'F'` as they need to be single characters not strings! I was going to paste the whole code in, then I thought it would be too long and forgot I had actually changed `draft()` so left it out. Opps :(

Comment: I've edited the answer again and put the entire code that I compiled and ran. And added a note about the single characters vs strings in `draft()`.  I've made rather a mess of answering this. But hopefully its right now.

Answer (score 1):

Two issues:

After the first call `scanf_s`, a newline is left in the buffer.  That newline is immediately picked up by the second `scanf_s`.  You need to change the pattern to match and discard any newlines by putting a space before `%d` and `%c`.  Also, you should check the return value to ensure that a value matching the pattern was read:

```
printf("How old are you?");
if (scanf_s(" %d", &age) != 1) {
    printf("You must enter a value age.\n");
    exit(1);
}
printf("Please enter your sex.(M or F)");
if (scanf_s(" %c", &sex) != 1) {
    printf("You must enter a value age.\n");
    exit(1);
}
```

In `draft`, you're using double quotes instead of single quotes for a character literal:

```
if (age>= 21 && sex=="M")
```

Here, `"M"` is a string containing one character plus a NULL terminator.  What you want is `'M'`, which is the character M.  So change the above line to:

```
if (age>= 21 && sex=='M')
```

And make a similar fix to the five other lines with the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is a problem:

```
scanf_s("%c", &sex);
```

Unlike conversion specifiers like `%s` and `%d`, the `%c` specifier does not cause `scanf` (and, I'm assuming, `scanf_s`) to skip over any leading whitespace in the input stream.  So it immediately picks up the newline character after your first input, hence why it doesn't wait for you to enter the sex.

To fix that, put a blank space before the conversion specifier:

```
scanf_s(" %c", &sex );
```

Another problem is your comparisons `sex == "M"` and `sex == "F"`; `sex` is a single `char`, but `"M"` and `"F"` are character *strings*.  Use the comparisons `sex == 'M'` and `sex == 'F'` (single quotes, not double quotes).